# good to ask (not compile-time force) subclass creators to do certain things?

Tags: c++

Is it considered good practice in c++ to ask subclass programmers of a particular base class to do things (without compile-time enforcing)? for example...

> Correct subclasses of this class should do these things:
>
> - Correctly populate the protected variable m_foo at the end of each call to the overridden virtual function bar() - see above comments (some c++ comments not shown in this SO question)
> - If these conditions are fulfilled: [some conditions] then at the end each call to the overriden virtual function bar(), call the non-virtual function baz() that is implemented in this base class. This is to perform some logic that should be common to all subclasses.

Are instructions like these for subclasses considered acceptable or does the fact that i'm not compile-time enforcing indicate that my code design is flawed?

Comment: Well, are these recommendations or absolute requirements?

Comment: @BenVoigt i want these to be absolute requirements, but i wasn't sure if it was possible in c++ to enforce it at compile-time. according to an answer below, something called the "template method pattern" could help me here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of your conditions sound like something that can be solved with a base-class wrapper for the call to bar(), e.g. :

```
   class base
   {
      public:
        virtual void vbar() = 0;

      protected:
        void bar()
        {
            vbar();
            m_foo = x;
            baz();
        }


        void baz()
        {
             ... do stuff ... 
        }
      private:
        T m_foo;
    }
```

Comment: Interesting, but is it possible for the base class to force the subclass to do something special like this in its constructor (not only a regular method)?

Comment: No, not in the constructor, I'm afraid. You could of course have a static helper function that constructs the object and then calls the relevant functions. You were talking about virtual functions as part of your question itself - you can't call virtual functions inside a constructor, so I didn't consider constructor a case you were asking about.

Comment: ok fair enough. But in your example, if we put the virtual function into private: (and bar() into public:) is it possible to compile-time enforce that subclasses will also put the overriden virtual function into private: (to prevent it from exposing it in public:)?

Answer (score 1):

You can enforce this sort of thing (without the author of the derived class needing to do anything) by using the [*template method pattern*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern).

Comment: can both of my things (and many other such things) be addressed with this pattern?

Comment: @user2015453: Yes, by requiring a particular return type in your pure-virtual base-class function.

Comment: Interesting, but is it possible for the base class to force the subclass to do something special like this in its constructor (not only a regular method)?

Answer (score 0):

Pre-conditions and Post-conditions are part of the method contract (software engineering speaking). So no, it's not bad practice to ask implementors to follow certain rules. Just make sure they are clearly documented.
Most of those conditions can't be checked at compile time anyways (though it's not a bad thing to check them at runtime...)

Answer (score 0):

The senior, senior developer (I guess we could call him architect) I work with likes to say "never ask, when you can tell."

What he means, and I happen to very much agree with, is whenever your base can force a subclass to do something a certain way you should.

Places this comes up:
1)  If a variable should always be initialized by the derived class (say a "name" for the class), it should be a required argument for ALL constructors.
2)  If you need to do some sort of logic before/after something, wrap the virtual function in a concrete one that forces the before/after to occur.
3)  If you are sending a msg of the same type, the packing of the msg should be in the base class with pure virtual methods extracting the data from the instance of the class.